# Git revert back to previous commit and keep committing new changes to master

Tags: git, version-control

I'm on branch master, head is pointing to my last commit A which is on master and I'm wondering if the following is possible:

1. Revert back to a previous commit B.
2. Move all the commits from B to A (B excluded) to a new branch "experimental". After this master's last commit should be B and "experimental"'s last commit should be A.
3. Make a new commit C after B under branch master. After this master's last commit should be C

All my commits are already pushed to origin, and my working directory is clean (no staged or unstaged changes).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b experimental    // Will Create and Switch your branch to "experimental" with the existing changes from master.
git push origin experimental    // Will Push "experimental" to remote origin.
git checkout master             // Will Switch branch back to "master"
git reset --hard <commit>       // Will bring the head to the <commit> mentioned. Also, will remove uncommitted changes from "master"
git add <files>                 // Add files to be committed to "master"
git commit -m "new commit C"    // Now you can do the new commit "C" to master which is your current branch.
git push origin master          // Will Push master to remote
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I'm actually following up with axiac to see what side effects should I expect given that I all my commits have been pushed to origin.

Comment: Even if you have pushed the changes. You can do a still "git revert <commit>" on master locally and then push that again to the origin. It will revert the "master" branch at origin back to the state you want. Let me know if that solves your confusion.

Comment: But would "experimental" get reflected in the remote repo?

Comment: Nope. You'll have to push "experimental" also. So, once you are on the "experimental" branch. You can do a "git push origin experimental". Only then "experimental" will get reflected in the remote.

Comment: Ok one last question. axiac is suggesting a git reset --hard while you're suggesting a git revert what's the difference between both? Also you're suggesting git checkout -b while he's suggesting git branch, is there a difference?

Comment: The answer to my second question is that git checkout -b will switch the current branch, whereas git branch just creates the branch without switching, so I guess I just need to make sure if there's any core difference between git reset --hard and git revert.

Comment: "git revert <commit>" removes the specific commit you want to remove as you asked in the question to remove <commit-A>. While "git reset --hard <commit>"  will bring current branch tip back to <commit> but will also reset the staging area and the working directory. So, you might also loose all your other changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87391/discussion-between-mechanicals-and-altn).

Comment: As, for you last comment. Thats why you need to checkout to "experimental" before reverting the <commit-A>. So, that <commit-A> is still intact in branch "experimental". Now you can go back to master and remove the commits you want.

Comment: I just joined the chat link, thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @ALTN: Updated Instruction set.

Comment: Alright thanks! I still think you should add the -f flag to the last instruction though and just mention in the comments "assuming no other contributor pushed new changes". The instruction set as is right now, will always result in an error at the end due to git reset --hard making local behind remote and preventing from pushing. Other than that, the answer was very helpful, it solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: @ALTN: The current code will result in error only in case if you are removing commits which you previously pushed to remote and now want to remove. If you hadn't pushed the branch to remote with those specific commits, and had commits only locally, then you'll not face the issue and will not have to do either pull or a force push.

Comment: correct, in my case I had everything pushed to remote. Anyways, it's all good, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's possible and it has no side effects if you didn't push the commits from `B` to `A` to a remote repository.

This is how you do it, in a different order than your list:

> 2. Move all the commits from B to A (B excluded) to a new branch "experimental"

```
git branch experimental
```

[`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) creates the branch `experimental` that points to the current `HEAD` (which is on commit `A`). The current branch remains `master`.

> 1. Revert back to a previous commit B.
> 2. After this master's last commit should be B and "experimental"'s last commit should be A.

```
git reset --hard B
```

[`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) moves the current branch (`master`) to commit `B`. The `--hard` option tells it to also update the index and the working tree to match the commit `B` (so `git status` will report "nothing to commit, working directory clean").

> 3. Make a new commit C after B under branch master. After this master's last commit should be C

The current branch is `master`. Do the changes you want, add them to the index and commit as usual.

Congratulations! Your `master` just diverged from `experimental`.

#### Remarks

You must have the working tree clean before starting. That means `git status` must report "nothing to commit, working directory clean" (it must also report you have untracked files that are not added to the index; you don't have to worry as long as the files are not tracked in commit `B` or any later commit).

If the working tree is not clean then you can use [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to put the changes aside to be recovered later. When you reach step 3 you restore the stashed changes using [`git stash apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I actually pushed all the commits from B to A to origin, what side effects should I expect and could they be fixed?

Comment: I think nothing wrong happens from the `git`'s point of view. Because you want to move those commits to an "experimental" branch it probably means they are not ready to be put in production. If this is the case you probably need to use `git revert` instead of `git reset` or other way to restore the working tree on the state it was on commit `B` then commit the changes to put the `master` branch in the same state is was on `B` by adding a new commit and pushing it (`git reset` kinda discards commits but the commits already fetched by your co-workers cannot be discarded any more).

Comment: after a session of chat with mechanicals [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87391/discussion-between-mechanicals-and-altn) we actually ended up going with reset because B is several commits before A. Can you please checkout the chat page, I'm currently testing the new instructions on a test repo.